# Forms in AMP on IOS

Tags: amp-html

we have a form - a search box in AMP.  It works perfectly. However on IOS, when you click into the form, it zooms in so it enlarges in size.  Also, while you can type into the form using the IOS keyboard that is displayed, when you click search - nothing happens.  So the only way to submit is by clicking the submit button next to the form.

We are using the AMP form custom element:

Any idea why it's behaving this way on IOS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please provide a link to an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is standard behaviour on iOS and not something you can "fix" within the confines of an AMP page.

Answer (score 0):

Text input form elements will zoom in on iOS if the font-size is less than 16px (or equiv). If you add the rule `input {font-size: 16px;}` to your style sheets it should fix the issue.

Note: you may need a more specific selector, depending on the other rules being applied to the form input.